# UIButton does not perform phone call

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Seems like this should be simple enough but for whatever reason I am unable to get the phone feature to prompt when my UIButton is pressed.

```
-(IBAction)viewMapButton:(id) sender
{
    NSString *phoneNumber = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"tel:1234567890"];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:phoneNumber]];

    NSLog(@"Call");
}
```

My NSLog is successfully called. I am running this just on the iOS simulator; is that causing it not to prompt to place the call?

Thanks!
Flea

Comment: I beleive you answered your own question :)

Comment: The iOS simulator doesn't have a phone, what'd you expect?

Comment: Thanks guys; just wanted to make sure! I was hoping the simulator would "simulate" the prompt but thats ok! Just wanted to be sure I wasn't missing something!

Comment: btw how to force iPhone to prompt user with question like "Would you like to call..." ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The iOS simulator doesn't have a phone (just like the iPod Touch), so nothing will happen when you call the `tel` URL scheme.

Comment: @Flea: finally you're gonna have to face the facts and accept this answer :)

Comment: Thanks guys; just wanted to make sure! I was hoping the simulator would "simulate" the prompt but thats ok! Just wanted to be sure I wasn't missing something!

Comment: @Flea btw how to prompt user to confirm call, before call action happens ?

Comment: @andi just create a UIAlertView.

Comment: I found simpler way: just replace `tel` with `telprompt`. I know that ther won't be this messsage but phone number and two buttons "Cancel" and "Call" are enough intuitive.

Comment: @andi You're right; I forgot about that URL scheme. Good catch.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII Do you know if it is possible to overload it with some prompt message without need to write own custom UIAlertView?